# Присвоение Bitmap для ImageView при помощи setImageBitmap. Один короткий вопрос

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview, bitmapimage

Известно, что `onDraw()` постоянно обновляется, что может снизить производительность устройства при одновременной отрисовке десятков объектов. Задержка процесса при помощи `postDelayed()` — не самый изящный выход из ситуации. В связи с этим, у меня вопрос:

Правильно ли я понимаю, что при использовании `Bitmap` в качестве ресурса для `ImageView` через `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` отрисовка происходит один раз и больше не требует ресурса на это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ImageView`, как и все `View` также проходит через `onDraw` в своём жизненном цикле, который вызывается при первой отрисовке, а также путём вызова методов `invalidate` или `requestLayout`.

Когда Вы устанавливаете `Bitmap` в `ImageView`, то ссылка на `Bitmap` удерживается внутри `ImageView` для отрисовки во время метода `onDraw`, который может вызываться неоднократно. Потому разделим ответ на Ваш вопрос:

1) Ссылка на ресурс `Bitmap`, для отрисовки в `ImageView` после `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap)`, лично Вам уже и не нужна. Т.к. она хранится теперь в `ImageView`, который отрисовывает `Bitmap` самостоятельно при необходимости.

**Важно**: Если Вы передали ссылку на `Bitmap` в `ImageView`, то сам `Bitmap` при этом не стоит изменять вне UI потока, потому что приложение начнёт падать на нативном уровне оставляя в стек трейсе что-то вроде `Signal 11`. Такие манипуляции **не являются** потокобезопасными.

2) Количество отрисовок зависит от количества вызова методов `invalidate` или `requestLayout`. Потому, нет разницы в производительности - будете ли Вы отрисовывать `Bitmap` самостоятельно в методе `onDraw` в собственной кастомной `View` или предоставите это дело на усмотрение `ImageView`. Достаточно заглянуть в метод `onDraw` у `ImageView`, чтобы понять, что там нет сверхъестественной отрисовки.

Метод `requestLayout` у `View` компонентов системой вызывается, когда меняются размеры `View` компонентов. Если Вы самостоятельно периодически этого не делаете, то система этот метод вызывает достаточно редко.

Метод `invalidate` у `View` компонентов вызывается системой когда в них что-то изменилось. Например Вы обновили счетчик у `ProgressBar` и теперь ему надо показать полосу прогресса на пиксель больше.

Методы `requestLayout` и `invalidate` вызываясь единожды в одном `View` компоненте, заставят перерисоваться всё дерево таких компонентов. А потому метод `onDraw` по сути своей пошагово рендерит картинку, отображаемую Вашим устройством:

После всех необходимых расчетов, начинается отрисовка. Сначала `Canvas` на котором будет итоговое изображение передаётся корневому `layout` в метод `onDraw` для отрисовки (например фона, если у него нечего больше рисовать), потом `Canvas` передаётся его первому дочернему `View`, чтобы тот отрисовал себя, если он является `ViewGroup`, то он передаёт `Canvas` своему первому дочернему `View` и т.д.. Пока каждый не оставит свой отпечаток на `Canvas`, который мы в итоге видим на экране.

Comment: Спасибо. Если можно было бы 5 раз принять Ваш ответ, я бы это сделал. Правильно ли я понял, что 10 `ImageView`, заданные через `setResource()`, будут тратить столько же ресурсов девайса, как если бы они были заданы через `setImageBitmap()`, при прочих равных?

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов Обновил ответ небольшим предупреждением. Что касается методов `setImageBitmap'`и `setImageResource`, то принципиально они различаются лишь источником откуда они берут `Bitmap`, На производительность отрисовки это никак не повлияет.